# Полное ограничения возможности авторизации на сервер всех пользователей в linux на время (только доступ ROOT)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, debian, администрирование

*Полностью запретить вход пользователей всех в linux на время*

К примеру 1000 user

> (только доступ root)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
touch /etc/nologin
```

Создайте этот файл, чтобы запретить вход пользователей в систему и уведомлять пользователей, когда система будет недоступна в течение длительного периода времени из-за выключения системы или текущего обслуживания.

Убить остаток user

```
kill -9 -u `who | awk '{print $1}'| grep -v root|head -1`
```

Comment: Ну, kill -9 всё-таки слишком грубо. Сначала хотя бы предупредить... `echo "Пожалуйста, разлогиньтесь на пару минут или позвоните админу" > /dev/pts/[0-9]*`

Comment: wall Пожалуйста, разлогиньтесь на пару минут или позвоните админу
Как вариант 
1 - wall --- Широковещательное сообщение от root@

Comment: Не везде wall есть. Нужен пакет util-linux (причом в генту с флагом tty-helpers)

Comment: Согласен  "Не везде wall есть"

Comment: А ещё есть `notify-send`, если дестокп.